How do you manage SQL triggers when using an ORM?
I have a serious question that I'm curious to ask here: How do you handle SQL Triggers when using an ORM? I'm currently using TypeORM (with Nest), and I'm aware of features like subscribers and event listeners, but these application-level solutions aren't as strict as an SQL trigger at the persistence level.
One idea I have is to manually create my triggers using SQL scripts and create migrations to use them during deployment. But in development, we frequently update our models, and ORM automatically syncs the database schema, so conflicts can easily occur with manually created triggers.)
I hope to discover a proper technique and workflow that has been experimented with.

Migration often requires a step where the triggers are disabled at the start, updated,  and re-enabled at the end after data validation.
